# Using Framed function on a list with MapAt

Tags: functions

Use MapAt to apply the function Framed on all the letter elements in the following list:

```
list={{1,2,"A","B"},{3,4,"C","D"},{5,6,"E","F"}};
```

While solving the above problem, the following MapAt identifies the third and fourth strings on each element on which Framed function is to be applied.

```
MapAt [f,{{1,2,"A","B"},{3,4,"C","D"},{5,6,"E","F"}},{All,{3,4}}]
```

Now, I intend to use Framed function. I tried the following way, which is not correct as the variable x understandably is instead given the value of "Framed" string.

```
f[x_]:= Framed
```

Wondering how to apply Framed function in this context.

Comment: use `f[x_]:= Framed[x]` or `f=Framed`?

Comment: `MapAt[Framed, ...]` or `f = Framed; MapAt[f, ...]`. The second one is an unnecessary complication though.

Answer (score 2):

Try also this:

```
list /. x_ /; Head[x] == String -> Framed[x]
```

Have fun!